# Почему компилятор выдает ошибку когда я пытаюсь добавить объект в Set?

Tags: java

Не могу понять, почему компилятор выдает ошибку когда я пытаюсь добавить объект класса Rout в Set rout?

```
public class SystemManager {
 Rout CI106 = new Rout("WizzAir", "Rome", "Berlin", 1, "06:00", "06:40", 25);

    Set<Rout> rout = new HashSet<>();
        rout.add(CI106);
```

Выдает ошибку: Cannot resolve symbol 'add'

Comment: Покажите код класса Rout. Помимо этого видно, что это только часть кода и не совсем понятно где/как Вы вызываете этот код.

Comment: Если у вас код такой как вы показываете, то вы пытаетесь выполняемый код писать в самом классе, а не внутри методов (или статических блоков). Нужно `rout.add(CI106);` перенести в метод.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код, представленный в вопросе, выдает ошибку компиляции `error: <identifier> expected`, вызванную тем, что инициализацию сета нельзя выполнять указанным способом, создавая экземпляр коллекции и вызывая его методы.

Нужно либо использовать секцию инициализации:

```java
// class level
Rout CI106 = new Rout("WizzAir", "Rome", "Berlin", 1, "06:00", "06:40", 25);
Set<Rout> rout = new HashSet<>();
{
    rout.add(CI106);
}
```

Устаревший *нерекомендуемый* способ -- double-brace инициализация:

```java
// class level
Rout CI106 = new Rout("WizzAir", "Rome", "Berlin", 1, "06:00", "06:40", 25);
Set<Rout> rout = new HashSet<>() {{
    add(CI106);
}};
```

Но гораздо проще использовать конструктор с коллекцией и какой-либо из фабричных методов, создающий коллекцию:

- "старые"

  - список из нескольких объектов [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))
  - список из одного объекта [`Collections.singletonList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList(T))
  - сет из одного элемента [`Collections.singleton`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#singleton(T))
- "новые" (Java 9+) [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E)) / [`Set.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E)) для получения неизменяемых списков / сетов с произвольным количеством объектов.

```java
Rout CI106 = new Rout("WizzAir", "Rome", "Berlin", 1, "06:00", "06:40", 25);
Set<Rout> rout = new HashSet<>(Set.of(CI106));
```

---

Ошибка `Cannot resolve symbol add` в представленном коде не воспроизводится и у неё другие причины.